# SQL Update table - 2 tables based on date - Table 2 Subset of table 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok I have a rather unique situation and I can't believe there is not a better way of doing this than my solution.
Requirements:

1. Table 2 - EpmTask_UserView_RM is a subset of table 1 -
   MSP_EpmTask_UserView So while all the fields match Table 1 has many
   more rows than table 2
2. Table 2 needs to get updated from table 1 based on the date a task has changed (We can't do a drop and replace)  There are three cases:
3. Task updates where something has changed about the task (We will know based on the task date stamp)
4. Task Deletes where a task has been deleted
5. Task Adds where a new task exists

I have 3 different queries that do this and am thinking there is a better way.

```
**** DELETE Tasks from ZZZ_TEST_OF_UPDATE_MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM table if no longer present in Production***/

USE [ProjectWebApp]
GO

        DELETE FROM [dbo].[ZZZ_TEST_OF_UPDATE_MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM]
        WHERE [dbo].[ZZZ_TEST_OF_UPDATE_MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM].TaskUID IN

            (SELECT
            /*Subquery to select all records in ZZZ_TEST_OF_UPDATE_MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM NOT found in MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM */
              [ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[ZZZ_TEST_OF_UPDATE_MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM].[TaskUID]
              FROM [ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[ZZZ_TEST_OF_UPDATE_MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM]
              LEFT JOIN [MSPSPRO].[ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView] as Prod
              on Prod.TaskUID = [ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[ZZZ_TEST_OF_UPDATE_MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM].TASKuid
              where Prod.TaskUID is NULL)
```

Query 2 the Update

```
    UPDATE [dbo].[ZZZ_TEST_OF_UPDATE_MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM]

SET 
     [ProjectUID] = Source.[ProjectUID]
    ,[TaskUID] = Source.[TaskUID]
    ,[TaskName] = Source.[TaskName]
    ,[TaskIndex] = Source.[TaskIndex]
    ,[TaskOutlineLevel] = Source.[TaskOutlineLevel]
    ,[TaskOutlineNumber] = Source.[TaskOutlineNumber]
    ,[TaskStartDate] = Source.[TaskStartDate]
    ,[TaskFinishDate] = Source.[TaskFinishDate]
    ,[TaskActualStartDate] = Source.[TaskActualStartDate]
    ,[TaskActualFinishDate] = Source.[TaskActualFinishDate]
    ,[TaskPercentCompleted] = Source.[TaskPercentCompleted]
    ,[Health] = Source.[Health]
    ,[Milestone Significance Level] = Source.[Milestone Significance Level]
    ,[TaskModifiedDate] = Source.[TaskModifiedDate]
    ,[TaskBaseline1StartDate] = Source.[TaskBaseline1StartDate]
    ,[TaskBaseline1FinishDate] = Source.[TaskBaseline1FinishDate]
    ,[TaskBaseline1Duration] = Source.[TaskBaseline1Duration]
    ,[QueryTimestamp] = GetDate()
FROM [MSPSPRO].[ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView] AS Source

WHERE Source.TaskUID = [dbo].[ZZZ_TEST_OF_UPDATE_MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM].TaskUID
AND GetDate() - Source.TaskModifiedDate <= .01 -- Update any task changed in last 14 minutes (14 minutes = 1% of a full day, ie '.01')

GO
```

Task 3 the add

```
    SELECT 
       [MSP_EpmProject_UserView].[ProjectUID]

      ,[TaskUID]
      ,[TaskName]
      ,[TaskIndex]
      ,[TaskOutlineLevel]
      ,[TaskOutlineNumber]
      ,[TaskStartDate]
      ,[TaskFinishDate]
      ,[TaskActualStartDate]
      ,[TaskActualFinishDate]
      ,[TaskPercentCompleted]
      ,[Health]
      ,[Milestone Significance Level]
      ,[TaskModifiedDate]
      ,[TaskBaseline1StartDate]
      ,[TaskBaseline1FinishDate]
      ,[TaskBaseline1Duration]
    ,GetDate() as QueryTimestamp


  INTO [ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView_RM] 

  FROM [MSPSPRO].[ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView]
  Inner Join [MSPSPRO].[ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView]
  on [MSP_EpmProject_UserView].projectUID = [MSP_EpmTask_UserView].ProjectUID
  WHERE [SMO Programs] = 'SMO Day 1 Release Management'
  AND [Milestone Significance Level] is not null
  /*AND [TaskModifiedDate] > (getdate() - 1)*/
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked at the MERGE statement in SQL Server 2008+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an ideal situation for a `MERGE` statement. If you haven't used them much or at all, I'd strongly suggest [this site](http://www.made2mentor.com/2012/07/got-the-urge-to-merge/) as a primer.

A `MERGE` can carry out `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` in one shot, in the right conditions. The basic idea is that you compare rows in two tables, your source and destination, and from that comparison (and potentially other conditions) you then take the appropriate action.

`MERGE` can perform very well because it carries out these actions in bulk - but do test it out. Sometimes people have found them to be slower than using the separate statements in some situations. Indexing correctly (Microsoft suggest indexing the columns used to join in both tables) can help immensely. Writing the `MERGE` statement correctly and well is important in terms of both getting the right result, and getting good performance - so definitely do your reading up if you haven't used them before. The above link is a good starter, but there are plenty of other articles around.